# Powershell returning different result for same query

Tags: powershell

I have directory that has subdirectories in this format `number-number-longnumber`
a few examples:

```
4-228-152283128912285
6-115-152336752325878
48-69-15232707627161
```

What I am trying to do is get the folder first modified and do some operations with it. Here's the query I ran:

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\moved-documents\' | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+" } | Sort-Object { $_.datemodified } | Select-Object -First 1;
```

This is giving me some folder,

`4-29-1522845689658894`

But when I run the same query, *without* the where filter, i.e.

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\moved-documents\' | Sort-Object { $_.datemodified } | Select-Object -First 1;
```

It is giving me some different folder:

`68-79-1522275846040235`

To make things even more odd, when I sort the folders in windows explorer by datemodified, none of these two folder come at top (or even bottom). Both of these (in fact, all *3* of these, 2 of these scripts and 1 that sorting in windows explorer itself) should return the same folder. Why are they returning different result and which one is correct?

Comment: This will be tough to figure out without access to the actual folders. Does it work the way you expect if you use `LastWriteTime` instead of `DateModified`?

Comment: One guess could be em-dashes vs en-dashes.

Comment: Yeah, the default date in Windows Explorer is LastWriteTime, not DateModified.  What do you get when you run `Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\moved-documents\' | Sort-Object { $_.datemodified } | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+" } | Select-Object -First 1;`?  Is there any suspicious output in `Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\moved-documents\' | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch "[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+" }`?

Comment: You could also look for files with unusual characters in the name with:  `Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\moved-documents\' | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '[^\u0020-\u007E]' }`.  That looks for files with any characters in the name other than ASCII character 32 through ASCII character 126.